# github: repositories with a repository

Tags: git, github

So I had a whole bunch of gists (all separate) and I just wrapped them up in a single repository by doing `git init` in their parent folder.

But now, from the parent folder's repository, none of the gist folders are accessible on github because they all appear as locked.

Does anyone know how to unlock them?

Or how I can remove each folder's status as a git without destorying the files and keeping them accessible from the master?

Comment: What exactly did you do to "wrap them up"?

Comment: Well... created a repo in the parent directory... and pushed it to github. I just fixed it though, I'm going to take this down soon (unless you think it would be helpful with an answer?). I needed to delete all the .git folders in all the gists, and then re init the repo in the parent folder.

Comment: Please put up an answer to your own question instead of removing it where you explain your solution. This may be helpful for others.

Comment: @iltempo Feel free to edit my question to make it clearer if you think that would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it turns out there is no way to fix this problem without starting over.

In every folder containing a gist do

```
rm -rf .git
```

In the parent folder also do

```
rm -rf .git
```

Now you can safely delete the repos on github

And then run the following in the parent folder to create a new repo with all the folders that were previously gists included

```
git init
git add *
git commit -m "init"
```